# How to avoid OutOfMemoryException when using BinaryReader

Tags: c#, image, memorystream, binaryreader

Hi I am working in an application where we provide option to user to change their profile image.

I am using file upload control to selecting files. It allows max 100MB.

But I am restricting the image size to 30Mb. Images uploading upto 20mb without any problem. When it is above 20MB it shows OutOfMemoryException. I am using BinaryReader to save the images.

```
var file = context.Request.Files[0];
if (!Directory.Exists(Folder))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Folder);
}

if (file.ContentLength != 0)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(targetFolder + "\\" + context.Request["Name"]) == false)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetFolder + "\\" + context.Request["Name"]);
    }

    var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
    var memoryBytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(memoryBytes))
    {
        var imageStream = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
        imageStream.Save(targetFolder + "\\" + context.Request["Name"] + "\\" + "picture" + ".png" , ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Is there any mistake I made?? Or Please suggest any other method to save the image.

Thanks in advance !!! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this answer gives you some idea http://stackoverflow.com/a/8613300/2263683

Comment: Probably won't fix your problem, but shouldn't you close that `BinaryReader`? Or use it in a `using` statement. Pretty sure it implements `IDisposable`, so you may have a leak there.

Comment: I have used BinaryReader withing using, But issue not fixed. I am getting the same exception.