# Why is BinaryReader hanging on ReadString() but not on Read()?

Tags: java, c#, sockets

Given a successful `Socket` connection, my Java server does this:

```
out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
out.write("HELLO");
out.newLine();
out.flush();
```

And this is what my C# client does:

```
TcpClient tcpClient         = new TcpClient("localhost", port);
tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout    = 10000;
NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(networkStream);
reader.ReadString(); // <--- Hangs
tcpClient.Close();
```

It will hang on `ReadString()` and time out eventually. If you change it to

```
reader.Read(); // <--- Returns 72
```

Returns `72` which I assume corresponds to the `H`. So apparently the Java server is indeed sending the message - why is `ReadString()` hanging?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8613300/3343533

Comment: @MitatKoyuncu - That will only work if the Java side closes the stream after writing `"HELLO\n"`.  (Think about it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mismatch between the format that you write and then subsequently read.  The docs for `BinaryReader.ReadString` say:

> Reads a string from the current stream. *The string is prefixed with the length, encoded as an integer seven bits at a time.*

That is very different to what you are writing.

My guess is that `ReadString` is getting a nonsensically large "length", and is trying to read that many bytes.  Of course, they won't be sent.