# How to save the docx binary data to file in web api C#

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-web-api, utf-8, docx

I'm fetching a byte[] of a docx file from one API to another and processing it like Application.Documents.Open(array); or File.WriteAllBytes(path, array);

I think the data received is in some UTF-8 format but i have no idea how to convert and process them

Fetching the file from the API using below code.

```cs
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    return result;
}
```

The output(byte[]) is received as string like this.

```cs
string result = "PK[][]?......";
```

Please check the [postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSOxL.jpg)
And trying with below code to save to folder but not working

```cs
byte[] res = result .ToArray();

File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\myfile.docx", res);
```

also tried this but didn't work,

```cs
byte[] mybytearray = Convert.FromBase64String(t); 
byte[] barr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hardcode);
```

Comment: `docx` files are really just ZIP files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use BinaryReader instead of StreamReader.
See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8613300/1438829